# Is it common to say X color filled Y shape?

Tags: word-usage

I ask this because I couldn't find any instance [on](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1263&bih=802&q=%22green%20filled%20the%20shape%20%22&oq=%22blue%20filled%20the%20shape%20%22&gs_l=serp.3...28439.29059.0.29208.5.5.0.0.0.0.135.384.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..5.0.0.aFrEoXOqBuo) Google.

Here's an example to illustrate the usage:

> The logo featured a cartoon whale drawn as a lower half-circle. **Blue
>   filled the shape**, with a white grid that made it look like a globe.

Is this a common usage or a strange one? If it's the latter, what's a better alternative?

Comment: The meaning is clear, but it is more common to make the subject the shape and not the color.  Probably just a bias towards thinking of color as an adjective

Comment: It sounds like personification to me. I'd say it is not common English. If you were writing creatively you could use it, though cartoon whale logos aren't usually very poetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine.  Think of drawing and paint programs, where you highlight a certain region and then apply the *fill* or *bucket* tool to apply a color to the entire selected region.

If it bothers you, I suppose you could say *The shape was solidly colored blue, except for a white etc.*

But, really, it's fine.

Even before computers, you could say *It was a truly beautiful day.  The sky was filled with a pure royal blue, untouched by a single fleck of cloud.*